# Checking for a css class on the nearest sibling() div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, siblings

Is there a way in jQuery to return the nearest sibling() div and check for a present class?

I have a visual verticle list of items, in which some items either have a 1px border (to set them apart - premium items) or no border at all (standard items).  While it looks great when a premium item is sandwiched between two standard items, when two or three premium items stack up the borders between them end up being 2px thick.

I'm looking for a way, using jQuery or otherwise, to check if the `<div class="item">` above the current div has the class featured-item (so checking if the div equals `<div class="item featured-item">`).  From there, I will set another class name to set border-top to 0px and make the visuals flow a little better.

Can anyone help me out?  Sorry if this question is convoluted, hard to explain!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ($("#current-div").prev().hasClass("someClass")) {
  // logic here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) gives you the previous sibling. You could either do:

```
if(element.prev().hasClass('featured-item'))
```

or

```
if(element.prev('.featured-item').length > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure you want to check the siblings or the parent nodes. Whatever, if "**above**" means parent, this will do it:

```
if( $('div').closest('.item').hasClass('.featured-item') )  { }
```

For the direct parent you might want to use `.parent()` instead of `.closest()`
If those elements are on the same level and "**above**" means "**before**" go with `.prev()`

```
if( $('div').prev(.item).hasClass('.featured-items') ) { }
```

References: [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 1):

forward `.nextAll([selector])` or back `.prevAll([selector])` or both ways `.siblings([selector])`.

If the div is truly one sibling before you should be able to do

```
if($(this).prev('.item.featured-item').length){
    // yes it is featured
}
else{
   no, not featured
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3D8E5/) fiddle should be what you are looking for.